# How do I set up a rails production server using ruby on rails?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I started learning about ruby on rails and heroku and I have come to the problem of not being able to see the newly created app in heroku. I tried running the server locally by using the command:

```
rails server
```

The app showed on the browser successfully but when I type the command

```
rails server -e production
```

The browser displays an error saying "The page you were looking for doesn't exist...". This is the same error I get when I try accessing the app through heroku. I'm very new to heroku and ruby on rails so I'm not sure where to go from here.

The console shows this when I try the -e production option

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
 actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
 railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
 railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
 activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
 activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
 activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
 railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
 activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
 railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
 railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
 /home/adcalder7/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
 /home/adcalder7/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
 /home/adcalder7/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to add an index to your root. Like this example shows: [Link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#write-your-app)